# 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment - Zapier - Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, zapier

I am trying to run the following code which loops through some data from a previous step and then calls a POST fetch command and I am getting the vague "'NoneType' object does not support item assignment" error when I test in Zapier. I have contacted them about it and they cannot support my code and cannot provide any better data on what's happening.

Any ideas?

CODE START

```
var noteEmail;
var noteSubject;
var noteDescription;

function attachNote() {
    fetch ('https://xyzdomain.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts/email/note/add', options)
   .then(function(res) {
     return res.json();
   })
   .then(function(json) {
     callback(null, json);
   })
   .catch(callback);
 }

var headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type ': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
var dataString = 'email=' + noteEmail + '&note={"subject":"' + noteSubject + '","description":"' + noteDescription + '"}';
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: dataString,
  auth: {
      'user': 'xyz@xyz.com',
      'pass': 'password'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
}

//Get Rep name by Hubspot ID
function getRep(repNumber) {
  switch (repNumber) {
  case "12345678":
    return "Steve Jenkins";
  break;
  case "90123456":
    return "John Jenkins";
  break;
  default:
   return "Dave Jenkins";
   break;
  }
}

var dataBody = inputData.Body.split(',');
var dataType = inputData.Type.split(',');
var dataEmailSubject = inputData.EmailSubject.split(',');
var dataCreatedAt = inputData.CreatedAt.split(',');
var dataCreatedBy = inputData.CreatedBy.split(',');
var dataMeetingTitle = inputData.MeetingTitle.split(',');
var dataStartTime = inputData.StartTime.split(',');
var dataEmailBody = inputData.EmailBody.split(',');
var dataEngagementId = inputData.EngagementId.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < dataEngagementId.length; i++) {
  switch (dataType[i]) {
  case "NOTE":
    noteSubject = "HS NOTE: - " + dataCreatedAt[i] + " - " + getRep(dataCreatedBy[i]);
    noteDescription = dataBody[i];
    attachNote();
  break;
  case "MEETING":
    noteSubject = 'HS MEETING: - ' + dataStartTime[i] + " - " + getRep(dataCreatedBy[i]);
    noteDescription = dataMeetingTitle[i];
    attachNote();
  break;
  case "TASK":
    noteSubject = 'HS TASK: - ' + dataCreatedAt[i] + " - " + getRep(dataCreatedBy[i]);
    noteDescription = dataBody[i]; 
    attachNote();
  break;
  case "CALL":
    noteSubject = 'HS CALL: - ' + dataCreatedAt[i] + " - " + getRep(dataCreatedBy[i]);
    noteDescription = dataBody[i];
    attachNote();
  break;
  case "EMAIL":
    noteSubject = 'HS EMAIL: - ' + dataCreatedAt[i] + " - " + getRep(dataCreatedBy[i]);
    noteDescription = dataEmailSubject[i]; + ' - ' + dataEmailBody[i];
    attachNote();
  break;
  case "INCOMING_EMAIL":
    noteSubject = 'HS INCOMING EMAIL: - ' + dataCreatedAt[i] + " - " + getRep(dataCreatedBy[i]);
    noteDescription = dataEmailSubject[i]; + ' - ' + dataEmailBody[i];
    attachNote();
  break;
  default:
  //Nothing matches do nothing
  break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You know you have syntax errors here, right?

Comment: Where? I used http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html to validate syntax and I don't get any errors. What am I missing?

Comment: Apologies. `noteDescription = dataEmailSubject[i]; + ' - ' + dataEmailBody[i];` is not a syntax error, but it is a bug. The `;` means that the ` + ' - ' + dataEmailBody[i];` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Your code is syntactically correct, so you're good to go there. [Standard](https://standardjs.com/) (my preferred js linter; powered by `eslint`) noted that there's some unreachable code, but that's not a showstopper. In your `getRep` function, you've got code after `return` (just `break`, no big deal) which will never be called. `return` quits the entire function, so it replaces the `break` you would normally need.

As for your actual issue, you're re-defining `callback` when you shouldn't be. There's [docs](https://zapier.com/help/code/#39nonetype39-object-does-not-support-item-assignment) on the issue, but the idea is that that's a function that lambda (where your code is run) defines. Redefining breaks the code runner.

Sorry for the confusion here! I'll see about throwing an error in the parser if you do this (or surfacing a better error).

Separately, I'm not positive this will do what you expect. Namely, you use `noteSubject` and `noteDescription` in `dataString` towards the top of the function, but modify it later. I don't think these changes will be shown in the `options` object. I haven't run your code though, so if fixing your `callback` redefinition makes everything work, ignore my suggestions. Also, to no-op the rest of the function, you can return `[]` per [these docs](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-examples).

Hope this helps. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks David! I am still not getting the exact modification of my code you're suggesting with the callback. I have updated with what I think you are saying and I cam still getting an error. Essentially, I changed it to:
<br/><br/>
    `function attachNote() {
      fetch ('https://rova.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts/email/note/add', options)
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    })
  }`
<br/><br/>
I am still getting the same error with the code change.

Comment: Of course! Your promise needs to end with you passing data into the callback. For instance, `.then(function(res){ callback(null, [{a: 1, b: 2}]); })`. If that doesn't make it work, can you re-copy your code into the SO question so I can take a look?